# Jade not finding view in different folder

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a directory like this

```
/Workspace
  /app
    app.js
  /lib
    /public
      /styles
        *.css
      /scripts
        *.js
    /views
      *.jade
```

from `app.js` in `app`, I have the following code:

```
libPath = __dirname + '/../lib'

... express stuff ...

app.configure(function() {
  app.set('view', libPath + '/views')
  ... express stuff ...
  app.use(express.static(libPath + '/public'))

... rest of the app ...
```

Now, the problem is that Jade can't find any of the views, but all the static assets are found. Thus, `app.set('view')` isn't working, but `express.static` is. If I copy the `views` directory to `app`, using `__dirname + '/views'` works fine. Anyone know why this is happening?

doing `app.get('view')`, I get a directory like this: `/Users/jong/Workspace/app/../lib/views`. I tried doing the absolute route `/Users/jong/Workspace/lib/views` as well to no avail. It's just weird that this directory works for static assets but not templates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a mistype, the correct option name is `views`, not `view`.

Configure your application like

```
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.set('view options', { layout: true });
```

But the main root of issue is that you seem to misunderstand how `express` (and the MVC at all) works.

`express` sends out the static data to the browser, using your `express.static` configure directive, once the request url matches the existing static file path.

Otherwise, it tries to find any defined route for the requested path and to execute the associated controller (which may or may not use the template engine in turn).

So, in order to show e.g. the index page (even if it has no parameters), given you have an `index.js` in your `views` folder, you have to do something like

```
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', {});
});
```

Comment: my god... it doesn't help that it works half the time with just `view`. UGH. thanks!